# Using last.fm API in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, last.fm

I have very little experience with web development. I have a little experience with HTML and I am learning JavaScript right now. I created a program in Java using a a last.fm library for Java. I was able to get user information, artist information, and venue information. Now I want to try and do that in a webpage, which is where my problem occurs.

I'm using the javascript last.fm api given here http://github.com/fxb/javascript-last.fm-api
I've downloaded all the .js files and they are in the same directory as my .htm file.

This is my code so far.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lastfm.api.md5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lastfm.api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lastfm.api.cache.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var cache = new LastFMCache();

var lastfm = new LastFM({
apiKey : 'c9946d11aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaace',
apiSecret : '9dabf9aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaxxx11ec3c7a993',
cache : cache
});

lastfm.artist.getInfo({artist: 'The xx'}, {success: function(data){
/* Use Data */
    }, error: function(code, message){
    /* Show error message. */
 }});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've dug around in the included .js files to try and understand what is going on. So on my initialization of lastfm, I am passing in some objects with associated values, which are then applied to lastfm. If I try and access them through document.write(lastfm.apiKey) I get an undefined value, which I don't really understand.

Also I see that I am calling getInfo and passing in 'The xx' and everything that follows. I don't understand how to use that Data that I believe is returned as a JSON response. How can I print the bio that is associated with that artist?

Answer (score 4):

the code that should go where you have written /* Use Data */ will refer to items such as `data.bio`. Try `alert(data)` to see what's in there.

I would also highly recommend using a JavaScript debugging console such as FireBug in order to really see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for this, really helped me get started with the api

Answer (score 0):

i just used this, and yeah. you just need to console.log(data) in the success to get info about the data that is being passed back from last fm